# jQuery keyup function doesn't work in function response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have problem when function response in ajax event keyup not work,
Could the value of ajax response is taken and used outside the ajax response function. this my code

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "tr", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode != 37 && e.keyCode != 39) {
    var ids = $(this).find("input[class~='form-control']");
    var harga = $(this).find("input[class~='field-harga']").val();
    var jumlah = $(this).find("input[class~='field-qty']").val();
    total = harga * jumlah;
    var id = ids.attr("data-id");
    var subtotal = jumlah * harga;
    var params = {
      'harga': harga,
      'jumlah': jumlah,
      'subtotal': subtotal,
    };
    var data = {
      id: id,
      params: params
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "<?php echo base_url('Penjualan/update'); ?>",
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        var dt = JSON.parse(data);
        subtot = dt.subtotal.toString();
        $("#subtotal").text(subtot); // this not working
        $("#grandTotal").text(subtot); // this not working

      }
    })

    $(this).find(".span-subtotal").html(total);
  }
});
```

Comment: put debugger and check the flow